# ajax or jquery doesn't show data Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, livesearch

I added a search field to show live my data, but nothing works when I fill that field.
I made a route called **retour.action**, and that's in my controller, so when I try a **console.log('test')** i can see *test* in my Console on my browser, but the rest of the code I made doesn't work, and I also get no error

here is my controller

```
public function action(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $output = '';
            $query = $request->get('query');
            if ($query != '') {
                $retours = Returnorder::all()
                    ->where('firmaname', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
                    ->orWhere('ordernumber', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
                    ->orWhere('status', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
                    ->get();

            } else {
                $retours = Returnorder::latest('id')->paginate(15);
            }
            $total_row = $retours->count();
            if ($total_row > 0) {
                foreach ($retours as $retour) {
                    $output .= '
        <tr>
         <td>' . $retour->firmaname . '</td>
         <td>' . $retour->ordernumber . '</td>
         <td>' . $retour->status . '</td>
        </tr>
        ';
                }
            } else {
                $output = '<tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="5">Geen data gevonden</td>
       </tr>
       ';
            }
            $retours = array(
                'table_data' => $output,
            );

            echo json_encode($retours);
        }
    }
```

And this is my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    fetch_customer_data();

    function fetch_customer_data(query = '')
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('retour.action') }}",
            method:'GET',
            data:{query:query},
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(retours)
            {
                $('tbody').html(retours.table_data);
            }
        })
    }

    $(document).on('keypress', '#search', function(){
        let query = $(this).val();
        fetch_customer_data(query);
    });
});
```

And the HTML is this

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="mTop">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @if(session('message'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{session('message')}}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">Retourmeldingen</div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="form-group" >
                                <label for="search" hidden>Zoeken</label>
                                <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="form-control"
                                       placeholder="Typ hier uw zoekopdracht in"/>
                            </div>
                            <table class="table table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">Firmanaam</th>
                                    <th scope="col"></th>
                                    <th scope="col"></th>
                                    <th scope="col">Ordernummer</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Status</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Verwerkingstijd</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Inzenddatum</th>
                                    <th scope="col"></th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Help me please

Answer (score 1):

I think you first need to be sure that what you're typing is actually being sent back to the router. You can get the value of what you're typing by using this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#search').on('keyup', (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" type="text" name="search" />
```

Comment: ****** gezeik wollah